# Graph theory: Determining $k$ from the chromatic polynomial

Tags: graph-theory

I know how to work out the chromatic polynomial of a graph and I can work out what $k$ would be by looking at the graph. Maybe I'm just being silly, but if you were given just the chromatic polynomial say: 
$$
k(k-1)^2 (k-2) 
$$
can you just look at that and tell that the chromatic number of $G$ is $3$?

Comment: What is $k$? It's not clear from the question.

Comment: Yes, is it supposed to be chromatic number?

Comment: Yeah the chromatic number, sorry I should of said!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p(k)$ is the chromatic polynomial of $G$, then the chromatic number of $G$ is the smallest non-negative integer $k_0$ such that $p(k_0)>0$.

In this case, you can clearly see that $p(0)=p(1)=p(2)=0$, while $p(3)\neq 0$, so the chromatic number must be $3$.

Comment: Thank you! My lecture notes have totally just skipped that

Comment: See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial), last line of Section "Definition".